# Why do these two tikz pictures give different outputs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

There are several questions like this but unfortunately the answers are specific to the particular instance, and none I've seen matches mine.

The follow two pictures have identical x and y label styles and yet the positions of the labels are different (see output).

[image]

I'm guessing it's the result of some interplay between the style keys and other keys, but I don't see how. It's not a big deal that they are different, but it would be nice to know why. Here's the code for both:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Exp_CDF}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1-exp(-(#1*x)}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        mark=none,
        domain= 0:4,
        samples=50,
        smooth,
        axis x line*=bottom, 
        xlabel=$x$,     
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        axis y line*=left, 
        ylabel=$F_X(x:\theta)$,     
        ylabel style={anchor=south},
        legend pos=south east,
        legend entries={$\theta=0.5$},
        enlargelimits=upper,
        ]
        \addplot[color=red] {Exp_CDF(0.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussPDF}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        axis lines=middle,
        tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        legend pos=outer north east,
         xlabel=$x$, 
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel=${f_X(x:c,d)}$,
        ylabel style={anchor=south},
        enlargelimits=upper,
        mark=none, 
        domain=-5:5, 
        samples=51,
        legend entries={$c=0; d=1$},
        ]
        \addplot[thick, red] {gaussPDF(0,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the `bottom` and `left` axes can have their labels below and left of the axes (because there's not going to be anything else) while the `middle` axes will have graphing on both sides of the axes – at least potentially. That's why the label has to go at the end. A similar difference can be seen with the ticks, one going only inside the diagram, the other ones are crossing the axis hinting at the axes styles.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel. Thanks, that makes sense for the ylabel, but I don't see why the xlabel should behave differently.  But this is definitely helpful in understand the choices tikz is making.

Comment: Because PGFplots doesn't change the axis style just because there's no graphing on the other side. Though, I assume you can do `axis x line*=bottom` in the second picture, too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel. Thanks again. More reading for me to do.

Comment: If you want to frame this as an answer I'll check it off.. There may be some unfortunate out there with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bottom`/`top`/`left`/`right` options for the axis lines have their label below/above/left/right of the axis because there won't be any diagram in the way.

The `middle` (= `center`) option needs to place the labels at the end of axes since it could overlap with the diagram itself.

Apparently, `pgfplots` does not change that behaviour just because there's no actual graph on either side of `middle`.

I'd suggest studying the [subsection 4.9.9 “Axis Lines”](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfplots/0#subsection.4.9.9) of the `pgfplots` manual since it also explains the difference between the starred and non-starred version and how they effect the placement of the axis labels.